# IPAD2 doesn't appear to record energy or network data

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Noob here so no hating please! :)
I saw the posts about using Xcode/Instruments to retrieve network data recorded on IOS. I have an Ipad2 running 8.3 that I'm trying to record network data while its being used and retrieve logs via xcode/instruments to troubleshoot network issues out in our environment. Started recording network data on the IPad last night, let it work all night with a driver, but there is no data when trying to retrieve with Xcode. I have the latest fresh install of Xcode on a MacBook Air, I can see the IPad when its connected to the MacBook, I selected the "Network" template, but there is no data when I select FILE/Import logged data from device.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.